# Append element using jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to recreate and append my template div to the parent div on button click and this can be done multiple times

```
<div id = "parent">
   <div id = "child_1">
       <div><input type = "text"></div>
       <div><input type = "text"></div>
       //several inputs and divs
   </div>
</div>
```

and my script

```
//on button click event
var template = $("#parent").children().last();
template.attr("id","child_2"); //just a sample of dynamic id
$("#parent").append(template);
```

But this doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `clone()` a copy of the child before you append it, otherwise you just put the current element back in its original position.

```
var template = $("#parent").children().last().clone();
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/6fr2d47g/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```js
var html = $("#parent").html();
var i = 1;

$("button").on("click",function(){
  i++;
  $("#parent").append(html.replace('id="child_1"','id="child_' + i + '"'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "parent">
   <div id = "child_1">
       <div><input type = "text"></div>
       <div><input type = "text"></div>
       //several inputs and divs
   </div>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
```